Kubuntu: display issue
I've been facing this screen issue for the past two months. It persists as long as the mouse is not moved. Moving the mouse stops it. I've been encountering this problem since Kubuntu 22.04.4, and I thought upgrading to 24.04.1 would resolve it, but the issue persists even after the upgrade.
I am not using the NVIDIA driver. I have Intel HD 520 graphics  with AMD Radeon M430 graphics.


What is the make and model of the graphics card and what driver are you using. It is not just Nvidia that needs to have the right driver, all video cards need their correct driver.

Intel Skylake GT2 (HD graphics 520) and AMD Radeon HD M430. I didn't install any driver separately, whenever I tried to search for that particular graphic driver I saw the message "all drivers are already included in Linux karnel, you don't need to install it separately". I didn't find anything.
